# Reconstruct columned data with merged rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the the following data

```
patient-id  last name   first name  date of birth   value   date of measurement
A1          A           BC          1900-01-01      1       1900-01-03 0:00
A1          A           BC          1900-01-01      2       1900-01-04 0:00
A1          A           BC          1900-01-01      3       1900-01-03 0:00
A1          A           BC          1900-01-01      2       1900-01-02 0:00
A1          A           BC          1900-01-01      1       1900-01-05 0:00
D5          D           EF          1900-01-02      4       1900-01-04 0:00
D5          D           EF          1900-01-02      5       1900-01-03 0:00
D5          D           EF          1900-01-02      4       1900-01-02 0:00
F2          G           HI          1900-01-03      6       1900-01-04 0:00
F2          G           HI          1900-01-03      5       1900-01-01 0:00
F2          G           HI          1900-01-03      6       1900-01-05 0:00
```

[image]

Each patient has a maximum of 10 rows. I want to merge it into a single row per patient.

For example, above data becomes:

```
patient-id  last name   first name  date of birth   value1  date of measurement1    value2  date of measurement2    value3  date of measurement3    value4  date of measurement4    value5  date of measurement5    value6  date of measurement6    value7  date of measurement7    value8  date of measurement8    value9  date of measurement9    value10 date of measurement10
A1          A           BC          1900-01-01      1       1900-01-03 0:00 2   1900-01-04 0:00 3   1900-01-03 0:00 2   1900-01-02 0:00 1   1900-01-05 0:00                                     
D5          D           EF          1900-01-02      4       1900-01-04 0:00 5   1900-01-03 0:00 4   1900-01-02 0:00                                                     
F2          G           HI          1900-01-03      6       1900-01-04 0:00 5   1900-01-01 0:00 6   1900-01-05 0:00
```

[image]

Does someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a helper column and a pivot table

1. helper column: add a new column in your table with formula:
   `=COUNTIF($A$1:A2,A2)`
   This will assign numbers for each measurement date per patient ID

[image]

2. pivot table:

   - add constant columns (which you need only once) as "rows"
   - add newly created column as "columns"
   - add columns to replicate as "values"
   - make sure "summarize value field by" is set to "sum" or "average" for each of them
   - set correct number format for dates
   - this works only for data containing only numerical information (= no text)

[image]

Comment: I came up with another pivot-less solution, but yours is more elegant and faster to implement!

Comment: @piko: there can be multiple good answers for a question (e.g. pivot-less solutions doesn't need to be manually updated). We can't know what's more important for OP.

Comment: True. I'll post it then! ;)

Comment: thanks for solution. i don't know what pivot until now, but i'll implement it when i can

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, less elegant than a Pivot Table and requiring a little more work, perhaps.

Let's assume your current data is in a sheet named `Old`.

1. In `Old`, make sure the data is sorted by Patient ID
2. Similarly to Máté's solution, add a helper column with the formula `=COUNTIF($A$1:A2;A2)`

You should have something like this:

[image]

---

1. Create a new sheet (e.g. `New`)
2. Copy the columns A to D from `Old` to `New`
3. In `New`, select the columns A to D, click on **Data > Remove Duplicates > Ok**
4. You should now have a unique line per patient (see the green area, below)

Use the screenshot below to build the rest of the sheet:

1. The grey area are the dynamic headers. If you copy/paste them 9 times on the right, they'll be updated automatically, from 1 to 10.
2. In the white area, there are 2 formulas: one to fetch the "value" and one to fetch the "date of measurement". You can also copy/paste them on the right, and they'll update automatically.

[image]

Here are the `SUMIFS`:

```
=SUMIFS(Old!$E:$E,Old!$G:$G,E$2,Old!$A:$A,$A4)              
=SUMIFS(Old!$F:$F,Old!$G:$G,F$2,Old!$A:$A,$A4)
```

---

**Note:** This only works with numerical values as well. For non numerical values, unique to each measurement and patient, I believe the only solution would be a VBA macro.

Comment: Thank you. However, =SUMIFS(Old!$E:$E,Old!$G:$G,E$1,Old!$A:$A,$A4) in E4 gives 0, in fact it should give 1... What would be problem?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer. Replace E$1 and F$1 by E$2 and F$2. I updated the answer above!